# Accessing data value from JSON with no key value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a question regarding getting a data value from a JSON array that has no key value in Angular.  I've seen plenty of examples getting the value out with a key, but I have not been able to figure this piece out.

The JSON that is returned from the API is quite complicated and looks like...

```html
[{"":796}]
```

Its then assigned in the controller using this..

```js
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/getnumassets'
}).success(function(data) {
  $scope.numAssets = data; // response data 

});
```

Now when I use the snippet below to get the number out, I get the following value: {"":796} when I want it to display 796.

```html
<div class="number">
  {{numAssets}}
</div>
<div class="desc">
  {{'viewport.totalAssets' | translate}}
</div>
```

I've tried a number of different accessors on the numAssets expression but I have yet to have any luck.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If that is the JSON you are getting back then I would say that it's the API that needs fixing and not your code.

Comment: Perhaps so... I'm pretty new at this whole environment.  The API is just doing a JSON on a select count(*) from the database

Comment: Well then depending on how it is translating the SQL output then putting `select count(*) as count` would probably give you a JSON output of `{"count":796}` which would be much better.

Comment: Derr.  Exactly what I was looking for thanks. Typically I just get a count back in C++ and use it... just a bit different. :)  Technically the answer below is correct and works but I prefer this method. What is the best way to answer the question?

Comment: Well Paul answered your question correctly as it is currently asked so I would accept his answer. And then just go fix your SQL and call it a day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If object is `obj = {"":796}` you can access its property this way: `obj['']`.

Comment: This works and I'm marking it as the correct answer, however I preferred Matthew's method of fixing my API to return a better JSON object.  Thanks!